# What sort of lock do I need?

Tags: lock, uk

Would anybody know what sort of lock do I need based on this pictures? I'll dissemble it if that's impossible, but I wanted to avoid having to do the work twice and just buy the replacement.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to change the keys, but also have a working bolt. This is in the UK.

Comment: That appears to be a well made old lock. You could get it re-keyed professionally.

Comment: @JimStewart: the house was built in 1992. By old, are you saying it's older than that?

Comment: Do they have locksmith in the UK?  I’d call one over here, find one that’s been in business many years and they’ll probably have any parts your lock may need.  He can also re-key the existing cylinder.

Comment: @Tyson: of course we have locksmith, but the reason why I'm posting here is because I wanted to it myself. I've change a few locks and even cylinders in the past.

Comment: The big point is the locksmith has parts! And can re-key without having to find that exact cylinder.

Comment: Also the locksmith requires an appointment and is very expensive (more than a whole new lock usually).

Comment: I assumed that locks in the UK would be built to last and hence would have a longer service life than their equivalents in the US. Styles of locks are presumably country specific, but I think that is a general type called a "mortise lock". Does the bolt not work on this lock? Sometimes the mechanism just needs a bit of oil.  Why is that "pin" projecting from the mechanism on the edge of the door?

Comment: Just go at local hardware store (suggest a family run one) Youll' fine people that will help you in replacing your old lock. even coming at your home to see exactly which model of lock you need.

Comment: Remove the lock set from the door and take it to the locksmith to save money.

Comment: If the latchset is working fine and you only need to change the lock cylinder to a tumbturn/key, RedGrittyBrick has the right solution. Either the hole has the screw in it to remove the cylinder or either one of the 2 phillips head screws do. Nothing will fall apart if the wrong one is removed. Once you find the right one, it is very simple to remove and reinstall.

Answer (score 7):

That looks like a Euro cylinder lock. You can remove it by undoing one bolt in the edge of the door then insert the key, turn an eighth of a turn and pull the cylinder out. Then measure the lengths in the diagram below. Or just measure externally.

[image: Euro Cylinder]

You should get an anti-snap lock which means you need to specify which of the measurements applies to the outside facing end.

P.S. The outside end of the lock cylinder should not project from the surface of the surrounding faceplate, get a shorter one if you can (though they are only available in 5mm increments). This affects security.

P.P.S. Locks vary a lot in price but this lock is protecting all your belongings so it is probably worth spending extra on a good lock. Look for the TS007 3 Star standard and kitemark.

---

[image: some cylinder locks]

Top: 35/35 British Oval cylinder with thumb-turn (see also Scandinavian oval cylinders)
Middle: 50/40 Euro-profile cylinder (AKA Euro-cylinder)
Bottom: 0/35 Euro-profile half-cylinder

Features:

- The threaded hole is for the retaining screw.
- The middle lock has the cam (actuator) in-line with the hull, in this position the whole cylinder can be pulled out (if the screw has been removed).
- There are blanking plugs in the holes which contain the key-pins, driver-pins and springs. These particular cylinders are not designed to be re-keyable.
- The reason I have these loose and not in use is because they have no anti-snap features and are mostly trivial to pick also.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use other keys, just change the cylinder from the [cylinder lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_tumbler_lock#Cylinder_locks). I am not sure how common they are in UK, but you should find them in any bigger utility stores.

Comment: I would like to get a working bolt as well, but even if I'm changing just the cylinder, which one should I buy? There are many: https://www.homebase.co.uk/search/products?q=lock%20cylinder&redirectFrom=Any

Comment: If you take off the inside plate and may be able to find out the manufacturer and details on the lock itself to get the info you need. You can also generally take just the cylinder to a lock smith and they'll rekey it for you to whatever key you want to use.